# How can a 4GB process run on only 2 GB RAM?

Tags: memory-management, operating-system, out-of-memory, virtual-memory

Given a 32-bit/64-bit processor can a 4GB process run on 2GB RAM. Will it use virtual memory or it wont run at all?

Comment: Pretty sure it depends more on how it was compiled and how much RAM the program itself uses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is HIGHLY platform dependent. On many 32bit OS's, no single process can ever use more than 2GB of memory, regardless of the physical memory installed or virtual memory allocated.

For example, my work computers use 32bit Linux with PAE (Physical Address Extensions) to allow it to have 16GB of RAM installed. The 2GB per process limit still applies however. Having the extra RAM simply allows me to have more individual processes running. 32bit Windows is the same way.

64bit OS's are more of a mixed bag. 64bit Linux will allow individual processes to map memory well in excess of 32GB (but again, varies from Kernel to Kernel). You will be limited only by the amount of Swap (Linux virtual memory) you have. 64bit Windows is a complete crap shoot. Certain versions will only allow 2GB per process, but most will allow >32GB limited only by the amount of Page File the user has allocated.

Microsoft provides a useful [table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366778%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) breaking down the various memory limits on various OS versions/editions. Unfortunately there is no such table that I can find with cursory searching for Linux since it is so fragmented.

Answer (score 1):

A 64-bit process needing 4GB on a 64-bit OS can generally run in 2GB of physical RAM, by using virtual memory, assuming disk swap space is available, but performance will be severely impacted if all of that memory is frequently accessed.

A 32-bit process can't address exactly 4GB of memory in practice (some address space overhead is required by the operating system), so it won't run. Depending on the OS, it can probably run a process that needs > 2GB and < 3-4GB.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Depends on the system.

Most 32-bit systems have a limitation of 2GB per process. If your system allows >2GB per process, then we can move on to the next part of your question.

Most modern systems use Virtual Memory. Yet, there are some constrained (and various old) systems that would just run out of space and make you cry. I believe [uClinux](http://www.uclinux.org/) supports both MMU and MMU-less architectures. *Most* 32-bit processors have a MMU (a few don't, see [ARM Cortex-M0](http://www.arm.com/products/processors/cortex-m/cortex-m0.php)) and a handful of 16-bit or 8-bit have it as well (see [Atmel ATtiny13A-MMU](http://www.atmel.com/pt/br/devices/ATTINY13A.aspx) and [Atari MMU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atari_MMU)).

Any process that needs more memory than is physically available will require a form of Memory Swap (e.g., a partition or file).

Virtual Memory is divided in pages. At some point, a page reside either in RAM or in Swap. Any attempt to access a memory page that's not loaded in RAM will trigger an interruption called [Page Fault](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_fault), which is handled by the kernel.

Comment: Even with PAE, most 32bit OS's and 64bit OS's running 32bit processes will only allow a single process to map 2GB of memory.

Comment: @aruisdante thank you for the correction. I did update the answer to reflect.